# Implementation of the ls command with several options

Tags: c, file-system, linux, posix, c99

As part of a past assignment, I've expanded on this implementation of `ls` to have more options available, including non-standard ones.

It currently supports these (described on [this page](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ls.htm)):

- `-a`
- `-d`
- `-h`
- `-i`
- `-l`
- `-p`
- `-Q`
- `-R`
- `-S`
- `-t`
- `-U`

Other than that, it doesn't list a `total` field nor does it have coloring.  It also doesn't have the same adaptive column alignments, but I have it done with fixed amounts so that it's still easier to read each column with `-l`.

I've already ran this through Valgrind with and without different options, and there appears to be no memory leaks.  I think it can still be structured better and simplified, though.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char* global_dir = ".";

struct Options
{
    bool using_a;
    bool using_d;
    bool using_h;
    bool using_i;
    bool using_l;
    bool using_p;
    bool using_Q;
    bool using_R;
    bool using_S;
    bool using_t;
    bool using_U;
};

static void init_opts(struct Options* opts)
{
    opts->using_a = false;
    opts->using_d = false;
    opts->using_h = false;
    opts->using_i = false;
    opts->using_l = false;
    opts->using_p = false;
    opts->using_Q = false;
    opts->using_R = false;
    opts->using_S = false;
    opts->using_t = false;
    opts->using_U = false;
}

struct Options get_opts(int count, char* args[])
{
    struct Options opts;
    init_opts(&opts);
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(count, args, "adhilpQRStU")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'a': opts.using_a = true; break;
            case 'd': opts.using_d = true; break;
            case 'h': opts.using_h = true; break;
            case 'i': opts.using_i = true; break;
            case 'l': opts.using_l = true; break;
            case 'p': opts.using_p = true; break;
            case 'Q': opts.using_Q = true; break;
            case 'R': opts.using_R = true; break;
            case 'S': opts.using_S = true; break;
            case 't': opts.using_t = true; break;
            case 'U': opts.using_U = true; break;
            case '?': exit(EX_USAGE);
        }
    }

    return opts;
}

static void print_permissions(mode_t mode)
{
    putchar((mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IXUSR) ? 'x' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IXGRP) ? 'x' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-');
    putchar((mode & S_IXOTH) ? 'x' : '-');
}

static void print_filetype(mode_t mode)
{
    switch (mode & S_IFMT)
    {
        case S_IFREG: putchar('-'); break;
        case S_IFDIR: putchar('d'); break;
        case S_IFLNK: putchar('l'); break;
        case S_IFCHR: putchar('c'); break;
        case S_IFBLK: putchar('b'); break;
        case S_IFSOCK: putchar('s'); break;
        case S_IFIFO: putchar('f'); break;
    }
}

void readable_fs(double size, char* buf)
{
    const char* units[] = { "", "K", "M", "G", "T" };
    int i = 0;

    while (size > 1024)
    {
        size /= 1024;
        ++i;
    }

    sprintf(buf, "%.*f%s", i, size, units[i]);
}

void print_time(time_t mod_time)
{
    // get current time with year
    time_t curr_time;
    time(&curr_time);
    struct tm* t = localtime(&curr_time);
    const int curr_mon = t->tm_mon;
    const int curr_yr = 1970 + t->tm_year;

    // get mod time and year
    t = localtime(&mod_time);
    const int mod_mon = t->tm_mon;
    const int mod_yr = 1970 + t->tm_year;

    // determine format based on years
    const char* format = ((mod_yr == curr_yr)
                       && (mod_mon >= (curr_mon - 6)))
                           ? "%b %e %H:%M"
                           : "%b %e  %Y";

    char time_buf[128];
    strftime(time_buf, sizeof(time_buf), format, t);
    printf("%s", time_buf);
}

struct stat get_stats(const char* filename)
{
    char path[1024];
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", global_dir, filename);
    struct stat sb;

    if (lstat(path, &sb) < 0)
    {   
        perror(path);
        exit(EX_IOERR);
    }

    return sb;
}

bool is_dir(const char* filename)
{
    struct stat sb = get_stats(filename);

    if (lstat(filename, &sb) < 0)
    {
        perror(filename);
        return false;
    }

    return (sb.st_mode & S_IFDIR) ? true : false;
}

bool is_in_dir(const char* dir, const char* filename)
{
    DIR* dfd = opendir(dir);

    if (!dfd)
    {
        perror(dir);
        return false;
    }

    struct dirent* dp = readdir(dfd);

    while (dp)
    {
        if (strcmp(filename, dp->d_name) == 0)
        {
            closedir(dfd);
            return true;
        }      

        dp = readdir(dfd);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "file \'%s\' not found\n", filename);

    closedir(dfd);

    return false;
}

void print_name_or_link(const char* filename, struct Options opts, mode_t mode)
{
    if (mode & S_IFLNK)
    {
        char link_buf[512];
        int count = readlink(filename, link_buf, sizeof(link_buf));

        if (count >= 0)
        {
            link_buf[count] = '\0';

            if (opts.using_Q)
            {
                printf(" \"%s\" -> \"%s\"\n", filename, link_buf);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" %s -> %s \n", filename, link_buf);
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    if (opts.using_Q)
    {
        printf(" \"%s\"", filename);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" %s", filename);
    }

    if (opts.using_p && is_dir(filename))
    {
        putchar('/');
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

void display_stats(char* dir, char* filename, struct Options opts)
{
    if (!is_in_dir(dir, filename))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!opts.using_l)
    {
        printf("%s\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    global_dir = dir;

    struct stat sb = get_stats(filename);

    if (opts.using_i)
    {
        printf("%ld ", (long)sb.st_ino);
    }

    print_filetype(sb.st_mode);
    print_permissions(sb.st_mode);
    printf(" %d ", sb.st_nlink);
    printf("%10s ", getpwuid(sb.st_uid)->pw_name);
    printf("%10s", getgrgid(sb.st_gid)->gr_name);

    if (opts.using_h)
    {
        char buf[10];
        readable_fs(sb.st_size, buf);
        printf(" %8s ", buf);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%10ld ", (long)sb.st_size);
    }

    print_time(sb.st_mtime);
    print_name_or_link(filename, opts, sb.st_mode);
}

bool can_recurse_dir(const char* parent, char* curr)
{
    if (!strcmp(".", curr) || !strcmp("..", curr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    char path[2048];
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", parent, curr);
    struct stat sb;

    if (lstat(path, &sb) < 0)
    {
        perror(path);
        exit(EX_IOERR);
    }

    return S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode);
}

void recurse_dirs(char* dir, struct Options opts)
{
    DIR* dfd = opendir(dir);
    struct dirent* dp = readdir(dfd);

    printf("\n%s:\n", dir);

    while ((dp = readdir(dfd)))
    {
        const bool omit_hidden = !opts.using_a && dp->d_name[0] == '.';

        if (!omit_hidden)
        {
            if (opts.using_l)
            {
                display_stats(dir, dp->d_name, opts);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);
            }
        }

        if (can_recurse_dir(dir, dp->d_name))
        {
            char next[1024];
            sprintf(next, "%s/%s", dir, dp->d_name);
            recurse_dirs(next, opts);
        }
    }

    closedir(dfd);
}

static int cmp_lex(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    const char* str1 = *(const void**)p1;
    const char* str2 = *(const void**)p2;

    return strcasecmp(str1, str2);
}

static int cmp_time(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    const char* str1 = *(const char**)p1;
    const char* str2 = *(const char**)p2;

    time_t time1 = get_stats(str1).st_mtime;
    time_t time2 = get_stats(str2).st_mtime;

    return time1 < time2;
}

static int cmp_size(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    const char* str1 = *(const char**)p1;
    const char* str2 = *(const char**)p2;

    long int size1 = get_stats(str1).st_size;
    long int size2 = get_stats(str2).st_size;

    return size1 < size2;
}

void display_dir(char* dir, struct Options opts)
{
    DIR* dfd = opendir(dir);
    struct dirent* dp = readdir(dfd);
    long curr_alloc_amt = 30000;
    char** dir_arr = malloc(curr_alloc_amt * sizeof(char*));

    if (!dir_arr)
    {
        abort();
    }

    long int count = 0;

    while (dp)
    {
        const bool omit_hidden = !opts.using_a && dp->d_name[0] == '.';

        if (!omit_hidden)
        {
            if (count >= curr_alloc_amt)
            {
                curr_alloc_amt *= 2;
                dir_arr = realloc(dir_arr, curr_alloc_amt * sizeof(char*));

                if (!dir_arr)
                {
                    abort();
                }
            }

            dir_arr[count] = dp->d_name;
            count++;
        }

        dp = readdir(dfd);
    }

    global_dir = dir;

    if (!opts.using_U && opts.using_t)
    {
        qsort(dir_arr, count, sizeof(char*), cmp_time);
    }
    else if (!opts.using_U && opts.using_S)
    {
        qsort(dir_arr, count, sizeof(char*), cmp_size);
    }
    else if (!opts.using_U)
    {
        qsort(dir_arr, count, sizeof(char*), cmp_lex);
    }

    for (long int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        display_stats(dir, dir_arr[i], opts);
    }

    closedir(dfd);
    free(dir_arr);
}

void scan_dirs(int count, char* args[], struct Options opts)
{
    if (opts.using_d)
    {
        const bool no_dirs_given = (count - optind) == 0;

        if (no_dirs_given)
        {
            display_stats(".", ".", opts);
        }

        // loop through directories
        for (int i = optind; i < count; ++i)
        {
            display_stats(".", args[i], opts);
        }

        return;
    }

    // no other arguments
    if (!opts.using_R && (optind == count))
    {
        display_dir(".", opts);
    }

    if (opts.using_R && !opts.using_d)
    {
        recurse_dirs(".", opts);
        return;
    }

    const bool multiple_dirs = (count - optind) >= 2;

    // loop through directories
    for (int i = optind; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (!is_dir(args[i]))
        {
            display_stats(".", args[i], opts);
            continue;
        }

        // display directory name
        //   for multiple directories
        if (multiple_dirs)
        {
            printf("\n%s:\n", args[i]);
        }

        if (!is_in_dir(".", args[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }

        display_dir(args[i], opts);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    scan_dirs(argc, argv, get_opts(argc, argv));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Range in `readable_fs()`.

   `readable_fs()` should handle even larger sizes - consider future growth, so expand to `K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y`.  [Ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)

   Pedantically there is no safe guard with `double size` not being some number like `1e100` and thus over-filing `char buf[10];`.  To limit only local code that understands the limitations of  `readable_fs()`, make it `static` and/or abort on insane numbers.
2. Naked Magic numbers:

   `(curr_mon - 6)`.  Maybe `(curr_mon - OLD_DATE)`.

   `can_recurse_dir() char path[2048];`  Why 2048?  Better to use a `#define CAN_BUF_SIZE 2048`, etc.

   `get_stats(const char* filename) char path[1024];`   Maybe `MAX_PATH_LEN`?

   `char time_buf[128];`  Why 128?

   `print_name_or_link() char link_buf[512];` etc.

   `long curr_alloc_amt = 30000;`  (Why 30000.  Why `long` and not `size_t`?)
3. `strftime`

   ```
   // Minor: () not needed
   // strftime(time_buf, sizeof(time_buf), format, t);
   // check result
   if (0 == strftime(time_buf, sizeof time_buf, format, t)) {
     // Handle failure somehow
     time_buf[0] = 0;
     abort();
   }
   ```
4. No protection from over-run in various places.  Suggest buffer scale by system macros `PATH_MAX`, `NAME_MAX`, etc.  Also consider `snprintf()` and check its results.

   ```
   // char path[1024];
   char path[PATH_MAX + 1 + NAME_MAX + 1];
   sprintf(path, "%s/%s", global_dir, filename);
   ```
5. **Incorrect** use of `qsort()`

   The compare function expects `+,0,-` on less than, equal, or greater than, not 0,1.  This can result in UB in `cmp_time()` and int `cmp_size()`

   ```
   // return time1 < time2;`
   return time1 > time2 -  time1 < time2;  // Or reverse time1,time2
   ```
6. Consider an easier to code `*alloc()` style: [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34382392/2410359)

   ```
   // dir_arr = realloc(dir_arr, curr_alloc_amt * sizeof(char*));
   dir_arr = realloc(dir_arr, sizeof  *dir_arr * curr_alloc_amt);
   ```
7. Why use type `long` when field is type `off_t` in `st_size;`?  Better to use `off_t`  and not change type.
8. `main()`

   I'd expect the program to return useful codes on return than only 0 to indicate success/failure/type of failure.
9. `const`

   Could use `const`, potentially better code and it conveys that `*dir` is not modified.

   ```
   // display_dir(char* dir,
   display_dir(const char* dir,
   ```
10. Array elements are better indexed with `size_t` than `long` in `print_name_or_link()`.  See also #2: last magic number

    ```
    // long int count = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    ```

    [Edit]
11. Above idea also applies to

    ```
    // long int size1 = get_stats(str1).st_size;
    // long int size2 = get_stats(str2).st_size;
    // return size1 < size2;
    off_t size1 = get_stats(str1).st_size;
    off_t size2 = get_stats(str2).st_size;
    return size1 > size2 - size1 < size2
    ```
12. To print types lacking a printf specifier, cast to the widest available integer of matching sign-ness.  In this case, "ino_t shall be defined as unsigned integer" [Ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html#tag_13_67)  and [How to print types of unknown size like ino_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844970/how-to-print-types-of-unknown-size-like-ino-t)

    ```
    // printf("%ld ", (long)sb.st_ino);
    printf("%ju ", (uintmax_t) sb.st_ino);
    ```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific way to format `off_t` in `printf()`, and other solutions I've looked at involves casting that value.

Comment: @Jamal Recommend: (best) `printf("%jd", (intmax) off_t_var);` or `printf("%lld", (long long) off_t_var);` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586928/how-should-i-print-types-like-off-t-and-size-t  IAC, that is for printing.  Continue to use `off_t` for math and related  variables.

Comment: Thanks.  I somehow didn't find the specific types for the others.  As for the returning in `main()`, I can change the relevant display functions to return `int`s so that they can fall back to `main()`.

Answer (score 9):

Looks pretty clean for the most part!  Here's the [source of the actual GNU implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-202.2/ls/ls.c) used on most systems for comparison (if you already haven't taken a look at it).  Just a few notes:

- Looks like part of this function could be converted into a `for` loop:

  ```
  void readable_fs(double size, char* buf)
  {
      const char* units[] = { "", "K", "M", "G", "T" };
      int i = 0;

      while (size > 1024)
      {
          size /= 1024;
          ++i;
      }

      sprintf(buf, "%.*f%s", i, size, units[i]);
  }
  ```

  Would still retain the same functionality, but reduce LOC and make it more readable/concise.
- I also noticed you have a magic number in the above function (as well as some other places).  I think it best in this situation to just place a comment above its usage to specify what that number is.
- I'm not a big fan of the `using_t` name, since the `_t` is reserved for POSIX type implementations. `t_option` would be better?  But if you change that one name you may as well be consistent and change all the others to be similar.
- Prefer [`snprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to `sprintf()`.
- You should use `size_t` in your `for` loop counter variable here:

  ```
  for (long int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  ```

  You could use this in other places too, as I see you are starting from 0 and only counting up (meaning you'd have no negative numbers, right?).  I'm not saying `size_t` is a good fit for every situation though, use the smallest type that will fit the situation as appropriately as possible to.  `stdint.h` is your best friend here.
- No reason to `return 0;`, can/should be removed.

Comment: Any ideas about the global (even though that source uses a bunch)?  it seems that I can remove its use in other places but `display_dir()`, otherwise the code would break if I specify a different directory.

Comment: @Jamal Here's a question for you: Is that REALLY needed at a global scope?  Another way to pose the question:  does it have the smallest scope possible?  If you believe so, then I think it's permissible.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is.  I could probably find a workaround if it were easier to pass around the directory, such as in the sorting functions.

Answer (score 5):

Well written code. Good job.

One thing I'd change is to instead use some meaningful name for each flag, instead of the flag letter. I don't recall by memory what `-U` does in the command, for instance, and so seeing a `using_U` in the code will evoke the same issue. You might remember the meaning of each flag right now since you have just implemented it, but I guarantee you'll forget them pretty soon. So I'd instead write `struct Options` someway like this:

```
struct Options
{
    bool print_all;            // -a, --all
    bool list_dirs_only;       // -d, --directory
    bool human_readable_sizes; // -h, --human-readable
    // etcetera
};
```

By the way, you're not handling the long form of each flag, which actually I don't think are supported everywhere, but as the link you've provided shows, seem to be defined. Should be easy for you to extend support for them using [`getop_long`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) if you're interested...

---

`display_stats()`, `display_dir()`, `recurse_dirs()` should all take the `dir` name string by `const char *`. The present non-const signatures pass the wrong impression that the strings can be modified. It doesn't seems to be the case, as far as I can tell.

Also, `global_dir` might be better named as `current_dir`? That one also should be a const pointer, regardless.

I'm not sure why you marked some of the functions `static`. All except `main()` could be `static`, but since this is a single file program, none really need to be `static`. So in this case, I'd personally go all or nothing.

---

I suppose that here you actually meant to cast to `char**` instead? It's all the same for the C compiler but might give the wrong idea to the readers:

> ```
> static int cmp_lex(const void* p1, const void* p2)
> {
>     const char* str1 = *(const void**)p1; // char** instead?
>     const char* str2 = *(const void**)p2;
>
>     return strcasecmp(str1, str2);
> }
> ```

---

This is silly, but that last line that breaks alignment really gives me OCD `;)`

> ```
> switch (mode & S_IFMT)
> {
>     case S_IFREG: putchar('-'); break;
>     case S_IFDIR: putchar('d'); break;
>     case S_IFLNK: putchar('l'); break;
>     case S_IFCHR: putchar('c'); break;
>     case S_IFBLK: putchar('b'); break;
>     case S_IFSOCK: putchar('s'); break; // <-- oh god...
>     case S_IFIFO: putchar('f'); break;
> }
> ```

Comment: I was hesitant about long options, but after just ten minutes or so, I think I figured them out. :-) I can work on that OCD spacing as well. ;-) I blame the Powers That Be for not making it `S_IFSOK` or something like that.